# Quick Building/Testing of assemblys

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am working on a class library which is compiled, and called as a reference in my original application. This class library is the printing functions of my application.

The coding of this requires a lot of backwards and forwards between the two projects, basically any test of the code I need to build the assembly library, go into the original program, build that (IE: to copy the freshly built reference) then start the application.....etc.... run the function.

Is there a quick way to streamline this process? Such as build my reference and inject it to the application so a restart is not necessary? The application passes quite a bit of database data to the reference so building a quick Launcher app is kinda out of the question.

There must be a better way to do this..... Thanks.

(Visual Basic (2015), .Net 4.5)

Comment: Setting the output of the Dll's build to the debug folder of the main app wont work because while running the application has the Dll loaded (File in use) I basicaly need some way (even temporary) of getting my application to reload the Dll each time any of its functions are called.

Comment: Why did you use VBA tag in this question? Which .net language are you using? Also, its better to move your own additional info in the question itself than adding a new comment.

Comment: I will suggest you buy a more powerful machine. If there is a hard dependency like you described, a rebuild is unavoidable. You might try to dynamically load the library via reflection if you do want to break the dependency, but that never is an easy task.

Comment: The build time isn't the issue, (i7...) Its this particular printing task is through quite a few menu's etc in the application so it takes a while to get there. The solution thou is quite obvious in hindsight.....

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is quite obvious in hind sight,

Copy the class code into the application and edit with pausing the execution in visual studio.

I can move it out when I have finished.

*Facepalm.